# Configuring python in RStudio, virtualenvs not working

Tags: python, r, rstudio, reticulate

Working in Windows 10

I'm trying to migrate to using python and R in r-studio and have followed [this link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023654474-Installing-and-Configuring-Python-with-RStudio) to get everything set up.

I have created a directory on my desktop called test_r and created and activated a virtual environment. I have also created a .Rprofile with the text:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "env\Scripts\python.exe")
```

I have set test_r as my working directory and restarted my R session, but when I run `reticulate::py_config()` R indicates that it is not using my virtualenv but is instead using conda, which I don't want as I would like more control over which python is being used?

```
python:         C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3
version:        3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.5

python versions found: 
 C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe
 C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe
```

I have tried editing the .Rprofile a few times and made sure that the virtualenv is running properly.

If anyone had any advice on this I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Is the "env" folder in your current working directory? You need to be careful when specifying a relative path like that.

Comment: Hi. Yes the env folder is in my working directory.

Comment: And you are on Windows? And `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "env\Scripts\python.exe")` runs without error? Because that looks like an invalid string. I would expect it to look like `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "env\\Scripts\\python.exe")`

Comment: I don't get any errors but it makes no change to the system. 
I have edited the ```Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = "env\\Scripts\\python.exe")``` but still no change.  

Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it with double backslashes. NB the name of the virtual environment is .venv in my case `Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = ".venv\\Scripts\\python.exe")`